# how to plot the equation a^2+b^3=0

Tags: plotting

**how to plot the equation a^2+b^3=0**
I need 
a in x-axis  from -10 to 10  & corresponding
b in y-axis

pls replay

Thanking you
Kiran mukund

Comment: Look up `ContourPlot[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[a^2 + b^3 == 0, {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

[image]